# Unity-Encrypting String using the Decorator Pattern

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to apply the decorator pattern to making an object that encrypts a word into a certain encryption, like the L337 method, which replaces letters like 9 with g, or 4 with r. Basically, I want to type a word into an inputfield and show the encrypted word in a text object. But I can't get the L337 decorator to inherit from the main decorator class. It won't accept the keyword 'super', so I tried the base word, but then when I implement Encrypt, it won't take the object newEncryption. Could someone help me figure out how to put this pattern together please?

I basically know what the decorator pattern is. It's making an object, making a basic decorator, and making a specific decorator, and instantiating the object with the decorating for exclusive methods and features.

```
public class Encryption : MonoBehaviour
{

public static InputField inputBox;
public static Text outputText;



public interface IEncryption { void Encrypt(); }


public class TextEncryption : IEncryption
{
    public void Encrypt()
    {
        string currentText = inputBox.text;
        outputText.text = currentText;
    }
}


public abstract class encryptionDecorator : IEncryption
{
    protected IEncryption tempEncryption;
    public encryptionDecorator(IEncryption newEncryption)
    {
        tempEncryption = newEncryption;
    }

    public void Encrypt()
    {
        tempEncryption.Encrypt();
    }
}

public class L337EncryptionDecorator : encryptionDecorator
{
    public L337EncryptionDecorator(IEncryption newEncryption) : base(newEncryption)
    {
        print("Encrypting L337 Code");
    }

    public void Encrypt()
    {

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to use `tempEncryption`, but you didnt really tell where you could not use `newEncryption` so im guessing.

But anyway, I hope this will clear some things up. Its slightly edited from your code so I didnt need to put GUI stuff, but you could just CnP it to unity.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Encryption : MonoBehaviour {

    public interface IEncryption {
        void Encrypt();
    }

    public class TextEncryption : IEncryption {
        public void Encrypt() {
        }
    }

    public abstract class EncryptionDecorator : IEncryption {

        protected IEncryption tempEncryption;

        public EncryptionDecorator(IEncryption newEncryption) {

            //this will be called when you override the constructor
            Debug.Log("In EncryptionDecorator constructor: " + newEncryption.GetType());
            tempEncryption = newEncryption;
        }

        //if you are going to override a method in a child class,
        //declare it either abstract ("no body; passes implementation to child") or 
        //virtual ("allows for a base implementation")
        public virtual void Encrypt() {

            Debug.Log("In EncryptionDecorator.Encrypt(): " + tempEncryption.GetType());
            tempEncryption.Encrypt();
        }
    }

    public class L337EncryptionDecorator : EncryptionDecorator {

        public L337EncryptionDecorator(IEncryption newEncryption) : base(newEncryption) {

            //newEncryption is a parameter, think of it as sort of a local variable.
            //but since you pass it down to the parent class, it gets assigned to tempEncryption
            //the base-class constructor is called first!
            Debug.Log("In L337EncryptionDecorator constructor: " + newEncryption.GetType());
        }

        //this overrides the base implementation. you can call it with 
        //base.Encrypt() though.
        public override void Encrypt() {
            //you have no parameters here, but you could use the inherited variable tempEncryption because you declared it protected
            Debug.Log("In L337EncrytionDecorator.Encrypt(): " + tempEncryption.GetType());

            //base refers to the base class
            base.Encrypt();
        }

    }

    void Start() {

        IEncryption encryption = new L337EncryptionDecorator(new TextEncryption());

        encryption.Encrypt();

    }
}
```

or maybe i missed what this is all about?!